# Mysql union 2 queries containing order by and random

Tags: mysql, random, union

I have a table with below columns:
id (AI), status (boolean 0 or 1), created at (datetime)

I want to get records which has status = 1 and order them by created at DESC, another get random records which has status = 0

I run code as below but can not return correct answer.

```
(SELECT *
FROM
    `Teacher` AS `teacher`
WHERE
    `teacher`.`status` = 1 ORDER BY `created_at` desc)

UNION 

(SELECT *
FROM
   `Teacher` AS `teacher`
WHERE 
   `teacher`.`status` = 0 ORDER By rand())
```

Comment: And what are the columns in `bouhun.missions`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UNION` set operator is forcing a "Using filesort" operation to identify and remove duplicates.

The `UNION ALL` set operator will concatenate the two resultsets without invoking the sort operation to identify and remove duplicates.

But with just replacing `UNION` with `UNION ALL`, we would be relying on behavior that is not guaranteed.  If we need the results returned in a particular order, then there should be an `ORDER BY` clause on the outermost query.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html

Excerpt

> However, use of `ORDER BY` for individual `SELECT` statements implies nothing about the order in which the rows appear in the final result because `UNION` by default produces an unordered set of rows.

...

(If someone adds a column to one of the tables, that will cause this query to fail with a mismatch in the number of columns returned.)

(There's an invalid reference to `teacher.status` in the second SELECT.)

(Personally, I would add a discriminator column to each set, and then reference that in an `ORDER BY` clause in an outer query. I'd also ditch the `*` in the SELECT list and specify the columns to be returned.)

---

I would achieve the specified result with something like this:

```
( 
  SELECT 'teacher' AS src
       , t.fee
       , t.fi
       , t.fo
       , t.fum
    FROM `Teacher` t
   WHERE t.`status` = 1
)
UNION ALL
( 
  SELECT 'mission' AS src
       , m.one
       , m.two
       , m.buckle
       , m.myshoe
    FROM `bouhun`.`missions` m
   WHERE m.`status` = 0
)
ORDER
   BY src DESC
    , CASE src WHEN 'teacher' THEN created_at END DESC
    , CASE src WHEN 'mission' THEN RAND() END
```

---

*** FOLLOWUP ***

The question has been edited, to change the table name in the second SELECT so that it is now the same table referenced in the first SELECT.

With that change, I would use just a single SELECT.

And avoid the `UNION` / `UNION ALL` of two sets.

We can just add some clever expressions to the `ORDER BY` clause.

Something like this:

```
 SELECT t.*
   FROM `Teacher` t
  WHERE t.status IN (0,1)
  ORDER
     BY t.status                              DESC
      , IF( t.status=0 , t.created_at , NULL) DESC 
      , IF( t.status=1 , RAND()       , NULL) DESC
```

Comment: Thanks you. it is perfect

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue a while back...
Something like this should solve it.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by `created_at` desc) AS RowNumber, `status`, id, datetime
FROM
    `Teacher` AS `teacher`
WHERE
    `teacher`.`status` = 1 ORDER BY `created_at` desc)

UNION 

(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by rand()) AS RowNumber, `status`, id, datetime
FROM
    `Teacher` AS `teacher`
WHERE 
   `teacher`.`status` = 0 ORDER By rand())

   ) order by `status`, RowNumber;
```

let's add a row index column(RowNumber) in table 1 and table 2 according to the criteria given to make sure of proper ordering within a status.
and we already have column with status value (`status`).
then just select * with order by `status`, RowNumber will give you what you exactly need.
[Pardon me for syntax errors in the query.]